# How to change animation speed during render in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I've create a simple **PlaneBufferGeomoetry** in THREE.js

*Geometry*

```
  const geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(10, 10, 10, 10);
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { side: THREE.DoubleSide, wireframe: true } );
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  const positions = geometry.attributes.position.array;
  scene.add(mesh);
```

I'm then looping through each of the array segments in order to randomly change the z axis position during the render.

```
  function animate() {

    render()

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

  }

  function render() {

    mesh.rotateZ(0.001)

    const geoArray = geometry.attributes.position;

    for (var i = 0; i < geoArray.count; i++) {
  
      geoArray.setZ(i, Math.round(Math.random() * -2));     
  
    }

    mesh.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

    renderer.render(scene, camera)
  }
```

This works fine, however the animation speed is way too fast. How can i slow down the time during render in order for the z axis positions to smoothly change?

I have tried setting a setTimeOut function during the animate function, however this just slows the framerate down and not the animation itslef.

Thankyou

Answer (score 3):

Right now, you are animating with fixed scalar values in your animation which is normally something you don't want to do in production apps. You should always take a time delta value into account so your animation is framerate independent. This makes it also easier to scale the time of your animation. So create an instance of `THREE.Clock` in your app like so:

```js
const clock = new THREE.Clock();
```

In your animation loop, retrieve the time delta value for the current frame and use it:

```js
const timeDelta = clock.getDelta();

mesh.rotateZ(timeDelta);
```

If you want to change the animation speed, multiply the delta value with another scalar representing your time scale value. E.g:

```js
timeDelta *= 0.1; // this will slow down the animation
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and it all makes sense. I should have taken the mesh roation out of the example as that's not actually the issue, its the setZ method inside the for loop im having trouble slowing down. Any tips?

Comment: You could try to implement the vertex displacement in the vertex shader. This will be a way faster solution however it requires some GLSL development.

Comment: BTW: If you update a buffer attribute per frame, use this line of code when you setup the geometry: `mesh.geometry.attributes.position.setUsage( THREE.DynamicDrawUsage );`. This might improve the performance of your current approach a bit.